# I am trying to get an icon array to display in my weather app, but can not seem to get UIImage to display them

Tags: ios, xcode

This is my code so far, with no errors, but it is not picking the dates from the 5 day forecast. What is wrong in this code?

//: to display the 5 day date array from the open weather API

`enter code here`var temperatureArray: Array = Array()
                var dayNumber = 0
                var readingNumber = 0
if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
if let mainArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "list") as? NSArray {
                        for dict in mainArray {
if let mainDictionary = (dict as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "main") as? NSDictionary {
if let temperature = mainDictionary.value(forKey: "temp_max") as? Double {

```
                                if readingNumber == 0 {
                          temperatureArray.append(temperature)
                      } else if temperature > temperatureArray[dayNumber] {
                            temperatureArray[dayNumber] = temperature



                                }

                            } else {
                   print("Error: unable to find temperature in dictionary")
                            }
                        } else {
                            print("Error: unable to find main dictionary")
                        }
                        readingNumber += 1
                        if readingNumber == 8 {
                            readingNumber = 0
                            dayNumber += 1


                        }
                        var dateArray: Array<String> = Array()
                        var dayNumber = 0
                        var readingNumber = 0

         if let weatherArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "list") as? NSArray {
                            for dict in weatherArray {
```

if let weatherDictionary = (dict as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "list") as? NSDictionary {
           if let date = weatherDictionary.value(forKey: "dt_txt") as? String {

```
                                    if readingNumber == 0 {
                                  dateArray.append(date)
                                 } else if date > dateArray[dayNumber] {
                                    dateArray[dayNumber] = date
                                        }

                                    }

                                } else {
                  print("Error: unable to find date in dictionary")
                                }


                                readingNumber += 1
                                if readingNumber == 8 {
                                    readingNumber = 0
                                    dayNumber += 1


                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }





                    func fixTempForDisplay(temp: Double) -> String {
                        let temperature = round(temp)
               let temperatureString = String(format: "%.0f", temperature)
                        return temperatureString
                    }




                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
```

self.weatherLabel1.text = "Today: (fixTempForDisplay(temp: temperatureArray[0]))°C"
 self.weatherLabel2.text = "Tomorrow: (fixTempForDisplay(temp: temperatureArray[1]))°C"
 self.weatherLabel3.text = "Day 3: (fixTempForDisplay(temp: temperatureArray[2]))°C"
 self.weatherLabel4.text = "Day 4: (fixTempForDisplay(temp: temperatureArray[3]))°C"
self.weatherLabel5.text = "Day 5: (fixTempForDisplay(temp: temperatureArray[4]))°C"

```
        func formatDate(date: NSDate) -> String {
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
            return dateFormatter.string(from: date as Date)


    }



                self.dateLabel1.text = ": \(formatDate(date: dateArray[0]))"
                self.dateLabel2.text = ": \(formatDate(date: dateArray[1]))"
                self.dateLabel3.text = ": \(formatDate(date: dateArray[2]))"
                self.dateLabel4.text = ": \(formatDate(date: dateArray[3]))"
                self.dateLabel5.text = ": \(formatDate(date: dateArray[4]))"


            }




                }

                    }





    dataTask.resume()
```

}

}

Comment: It would help if we could see the json data for the icon part. The parameter you send to the UIImage constructor looks strange, are those really the names of your icons?

Comment: What is this `"iconArray, scale: [0]"`? You know it's looking of an image named "iconArray, scale: [0]"?

Comment: I pulled off the the "scale" that was a correct fix from Xcode, but still no success. For Joakim - "weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"}]  I have the 01d icon plus all the icons in my Xcode app. and I can pull the Icons on my View Controller for the daily weather using this self.iconImage.image = UIImage(named: weatherIcon) but it is the 5 day "Array" now this self.iconImage1.image = UIImage(named: "icon:[0]" )
                                            self.iconImage2.image = UIImage(named: "icon:[1]") etc. that is still not working.

Comment: also tried this:                                                            self.iconImage1.image = UIImage(named: ": \(iconArray[0])") self.iconImage2.image = UIImage(named: ": \(iconArray[1])")

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you need to change your icon array to contain strings

```
var iconArray: Array<String> = Array()
```

and then when parsing the json text

```
if let icon = weatherDictionary.value(forKey: "icon") as? String {
```

and finally

```
self.iconImage1.image = UIImage(named: iconArray[0])
self.iconImage2.image = UIImage(named: iconArray[1])
```

Of course the below comparison won't work anymore when icon is a string but I don't understand any of this if/else clasue so I don't know what to replace it with

```
if readingNumber == 0 {
  iconArray.append(icon)
} else if icon > iconArray[dayNumber] { //This won't work now. 
  iconArray[dayNumber] = icon
}
```

Comment: All that worked, still not able to produce the icon from the API, no build errors. Any ideas how to proceed from here?

Comment: And you have an image named "01d" in your Assets catalog in Xcode?

Comment: @RichJ The `UIImage(named: "MyImage")` assumes  you have an image with the name "MyImage". What are the names of the images you have? When you write something like `"iconArray, scale: [0]"` as the image name, it looks like you have no concept of what you're passing there.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, yes I have all the Icon Images 01d, 01n, 02d, 02n etc.

Comment: @RichJ, I had missed that you set the image (self.iconImage1.image...) in the innermost loop, this should be done after you are done with parsing the json data so after the  "if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization... {}" block.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, it is after, and I have thought about this and I truly believe it should be a Double not a String. I would like to post the updated code for you to look at, although I am still not getting the icons to display in my App.

Comment: Yes, the indentation fooled me. Add the updated code to the question and I'll look at it.

Comment: I think I need another "get" I trying to pull the data on the same getTemperature() from the Controller, Think the code is right, but I need have getIcon() in the code as well. How do you do this on the same button @IBAction func updateTemperature(_ sender: UIButton) {
        getTemperature() ? or do you have to have a separate call?

Comment: I have no idea what getTemperature() does and you kind of lost me here but in general, yes you can of course call many methods from the same IBAction func

Comment: I realized I don't need the another "get" I went back to String and I am almost there I just need to know how fix the "Use of unresolved identifier 'iconArray'  error is this code self.iconImage1.image = UIImage(named: iconArray[0])
self.iconImage2.image = UIImage(named: iconArray[1])

Comment: If you still have that code inside the Dispatch.main.async{} block you need to access the property using self, self.iconArray...

Comment: If I do that I get this error "Value of type 'FiveDayWeatherViewController' has no member 'iconArray' "

Comment: Sorry, I forgot they where local variables in the getIcon method. I have no idea what you have done to your code if you can't access iconArray anymore. Have you moved iconAray?

Comment: Is there anyway I can post the whole code so you can look at it? I am also trying with the dateArray and getting the same error?

Comment: Add it to the question

Comment: Do I do that in the Answer Question area?

Comment: No I meant that you should append it to your question.